# How do I call static functions by variable in PHP?

Tags: php

When I use the code below it throws an error even though the function looks well formed. (FYI I also tried valid and static prefixes.)

---

Function call:

```
foreach ($this->errorList as $field => $error_msg) {
            // check for valid input and store cleaned vars
            $this->goodInput[$field] = Valid::__($field);
}
```

---

Result:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Valid::email()

---

Code:

```
class Valid
{
    public static function __($name)
    {
        // this is what I tried:
        // $checkFunction = 'self::' . $name;
        // return $checkFunction();

        // this works:
        // Thank you to fusion3k and Darren
        return self::$name();
    }

    private static function email()
    {
        //sanitize and validate email field
    }

    // other methods for other fields
    // ...

    // default method to sanitize input for display in email
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $_POST)) {
            $clean_var = trim($_POST[$name]);
            $clean_var = stripslashes($clean_var);    
            $clean_var = htmlspecialchars($clean_var);
            return $clean_var;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how you do a dynamic static method like that but it won't be like that. You can't substitute `'Valid::'` for `Valid::`

Comment: What would happen if you replaced Valid:: with self:: in your first function?

Comment: Simply use `return self::$name();` (no `$checkFunction` needed) (see [demo](https://eval.in/536484))

Comment: @Rasclatt There's lots of potential problems with his code, but I think you can call a function like that. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: I see in v7 it appears to be able to handle a stringed class variable like the OP is demonstrating in example #4. I think a better option is the self::$name option

Comment: @blazerunner44 I really have no idea what I am doing. Would you mind pointing out some of the potential problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you instantiate your class somewhere properly first right? Well it's best to check that a said method exists, and harness `self::`. Also, [*as @fusion3k said*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001798/how-do-i-call-static-functions-by-variable-in-php/36002008#comment59656333_36001798), better to return `self::$name()`. Here's an example of what you should be doing:

```
public static function __($name) {
    if(method_exists(new self, $name)) {
        return self::$name();
    }
}
```

In all honesty, this isn't the best way for you to be doing it. You should be looking into [`call_func_user_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to manage this kind of implementation properly. Allowing the parsing of arguments to called methods.

Comment: I am looking into call_func_user_array() but I have no idea what I'm doing. (I am a dilettante programmer.)  Would that function make sense in the context I am calling from? See my edit.

Comment: Also, why would I need to check if method exists if I am using the call static catch all?

Comment: @Pellinore read up on [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/method_exists) - it essentially makes sure that your `email()` method, or **any** methods you're trying to call, exist inside the class, so that you don't run into any issues in the future.

Comment: I was actually intentionally using the callStatic method as the default handler. For strings for instance, like name, message, and subject. No reason to have separate methods for those.I suppose I could use an if-else tree to send it to the right method, but I felt this was cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any object created when you call an static function then Valid functions are not accessible. Try like this

```
public static function __($name) { 
$valid = new Valid ();
return $valid::$name(); 
}
```